# Magento OnePage Checkout Conflict with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, magento, prototypejs, conflict

i am using Magento 1.8.1 i have used responsive navigation menu and for this i have to use jQuery if i put jQuery on my checkout stops working.

i have changed the placement and placed no conflicts on various but either checkout stop working or mostly menu stop working after noConflict.

please help me regarding this i am working on it from last 3 days but fed up of it. can't find any solution to solve it out. have working in a website its working fine but this site creating problem.

Comment: please give link to site ,so i can solve it.

Comment: http://icandycords.com/mob/checkout/onepage/index/ here it is @Pratik Joshi

Comment: You have not included jQuery JS file in ur page in HEAD before any script <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: refersh now its added in bottom http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

Comment: No, Include  it in HEAD AT the start of any script not at the bottom.please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check `Multiple jQuery.js exiting in` your page. If existing then remove Jquery js files except one Jquery Lib file.
2. first put prototype.js,then jQuery.js Jquery lib and after thet put jquery.noconflict.js
   jquery.noconflict.js is consist of this code `jQuery.noConflict();`
3. If upto 2 point gives any solution then modify code for jquery.noconflict.js
   is

`jQuery.noConflict();
var $j = jQuery;`

And use $j instead of $jQuery just like:

`jQuery(document).ready (
$j(document).ready (`

According prototype.js Is used $ is it variable so do not used $ as jQuery.